# How to customize parallel categories diagram colors with plotly ? Python edition

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm trying to perform a full colored custom parallel categories diagram from Plotly but I can't. The documentation about the subject is utterly empty : https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.parcats.line.colorbar.html and I did not find a example.

[I currently have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp6ka.png)

[And this is what I want (thank you Paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFnxY.png)

3 Columns, 1 with only one categorie ('Base' here), 2 with 2 categories ('10' and '15' here)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please read about [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From examples in documentations [here](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/) and the output (if you are in jupyter) of `go.Sankey.link?` you could check that you can modify the color of every link using `color`.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A2, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2],
      color = ["red", "green", "orange", "red", "yellow", "green"]
  ))])

fig.show()
```

[image]